# Search view profile to show only the primary phone number

Tags: contact-view, phone, primary

Is there a way to set up a search view profile so that it shows the primary phone number for a contact regardless of what type of phone it is?  When setting up this profile, I am required to indicate a type of phone.  I want to be able to see results that show the primary phone regardless of type.  Thanks.

[image: Screenshot from profile settings]

We are using version 4.7.24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, there should be an option with the label `-any-` in the above select input. But as it is not present, I don't think there is any UI setting to accept all phone type values for the profile field.

Maybe, you can try API to trigger this (`Support -> Developer -> API Explorer`) OR `http://domainname/civicrm/api#explorer`.

Select Entity as `UFField` and action as `create` and form the API something like -

```
$result = civicrm_api3('UFField', 'create', array(
  'id' => <uf_field_id>,
  'field_name' => "phone",
  'phone_type_id' => 0,
));
```

The first param is the `uf_field_id` which is the id of the profile field created in your screenshot.

If you don't find the id, you can check by placing your cursor on the `Edit` link on the field row displayed for your profile. The URL will be shown on the bottom left of your browser. For eg: in the screenshot below 75 is the value of the field id.

[image]

Comment: Nice suggestion - I actually got it to work (i didn't test using the api, but with straight SQL). I configured the profile field to use the primary phone of type home. Then, taking the id of the profile field, I ran `update civicrm_uf_field set phone_type_id = NULL where id = 161` and it seems to work.